# Haskell Diagrams Output without commandline

Tags: haskell, svg, haskell-diagrams

I have one question: I know how to output svg file with a help of   `ghc --make Strukturine.hs`   command in Terminal. As I understood it uses   `import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine`   . Is it possible somehow load Strukturine.hs file with the help of `:load Strukturine.hs` in terminal and then just put the name of function for example: strukturine. That function should output a scheme/picture (to svg file).

The beginning of Strukturine.hs file looks like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Strukturine where

import Diagrams.Prelude

import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine

import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

import Data.Char

import Input

import qualified Input(getNumber) --other module

main = mainWith(strukturine :: Diagram B R2)
```

Comment: Loading the module in ghci and typing `main` should have the same effect as `runghc Strukturine.hs`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function renderSVG from Diagrams.Backend.SVG.

```
renderSVG :: FilePath -> SizeSpec2D -> Diagram SVG R2 -> IO ()
```

For example to render a 400x400 svg:

```
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG (renderSVG)

outputFile :: FilePath
outputFile = "strukturine.svg"

dimensions :: SizeSpec2D
dimensions = mkSizeSpec (Just 400) (Just 400)

strukturineDiagram :: Diagram SVG R2

strukturine = do renderSVG outputFile dimensions strukturineDiagram
```

See [http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-Backend-SVG.html#v:renderSVG](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/Diagrams-Backend-SVG.html#v%3arenderSVG)

And for more specific rendering, see: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/cmdline.html